# Which properties define "auto mount" directory names?

Tags: automount

I have a second hard drive that I am regularly adding to my Laptop in order to store backup data there.

Earlier on, after I logged in, the drive showed up in the unity launcher, I could click it, and it became mounted as "/media/myuserid/backup".

Today, I had to give away the drive to a coworker, he used it for some installation. After I got it back, I just wiped his stuff, created a single ext4 partition, labeled it "backup", like I did when initially preparing that disk.

But now, when I click the "drive icon" in the launcher, the drive gets mounted like
/media/myuserid/partition--uuid

So instead of using my label "backup", it is mounted under the UUID of the partition.
Honestly, I liked the other behavior much better.

Any idea what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For any FAT the label apply:

  ```
  /media/user/label
  ```
- For NTFS the serial:

  ```
  /media/user/serial
  ```
- For ext2/3/4 the UUID:

  ```
  /media/user/UUID
  ```
- Others (HSF+, XFS, ZFS, etc. etc.) use any unique identifier if they use any or label if they don't have.
- Network filesystem (SMB, NFS, etc.) use the name of the resource:

  ```
  //server/resource
  ```

  becomes:

  ```
  /media/user/resource
  ```

> created a single ext4 partition, labeled it "backup", like I did when initially preparing that disk.

In this case, the media was mounted using the UUID. You can unmount the drive and make gvfs "forget" the name of the filesystem it used previously using the "Disk" utility or assign manually a mountpoint.